# Android - accessing assets from another class isn't working

Tags: android

I'm trying to access my application's assets from another class file. Obviously `this.getAssets()` doesn't work, so I tried passing the Context to the class as a parameter. I used a variety of 'contexts' - `getBaseContext()`, `getApplicationContext()`, this, but they all result in a `NullPointerException`.

Here is the code I am using. It runs fine inside the Activity, but I can't work out how to make it work in an external class.

```
private String pickText(){
    String line = null;
    try {
        AssetManager am = this.getAssets();
        InputStream fstream = am.open("plan.txt");
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        line = br.readLine();
        for(int i = 1; i < id && line != null; i++){
            line = br.readLine();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return line;
}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: where you are calling pickText() method? if in activity then pass Context in it

Comment: I have plenty of different Activities and all access the Assets with simply using "getAssets". Perhaps your class needs to extend "Activity".

Comment: Sorry, should have made it clearer - second class is NOT an Activity. It's an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass in the activity itself as the parameter, meaning `this` from your Activty.

Comment: Is that the current Activity still?

Comment: Yes. There's one Activity and then several other object classes.

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the NullPointer?

Comment: When I use context.getAssets().

Comment: Not "when", where? Are you getting the NullPointer on the line `AssetManager am = context.getAssets();` ? And you set the context where and how?

Comment: Yes, on that line. I passed the context into this class using a parameter in a constructor. It looks like this:
`new Planet(this, 300, 300);`
Where 'this' is supposed to be a Context.

Comment: My apologies, the error was elsewhere in code! Sorry for wasting your time and thanks for your help. :)